# Oracle doesn't concatenate after TZ_OFFSET()

Tags: oracle, concatenation, string-concatenation, timezone-offset

Concatenation after performing TZ_OFFSET doesn't seem to register.
Example:

```
SELECT '[' || TZ_OFFSET('Europe/Amsterdam') || ']' FROM DUAL
```

results in:

```
[+01:00
```

Why doesn't the concatenation after TZ_OFFSET() take place?

Comment: Works for me - http://rextester.com/DMQSU85214

Comment: That's odd, it doesn't for me - https://snag.gy/wigrFJ.jpg

Comment: Even that worked correctly here - http://rextester.com/ESB48246 Not sure what causes the problem in your case.

Comment: It might be a bug in your version of Oracle. What version are you running with? (You can check by running `SELECT VERSION FROM v$instance;`)

Comment: Hmmmm, this doesn't work for me on 11.2.0.4 SE. Even when using a sub_query or CTE. Interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug (1937516, which I can't see; also 9861391, which refers to base bug 17291158, which I also can't see), combined with client behaviour. In SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, this looks OK - sort of:

```
select '[' || tz_offset('Europe/Amsterdam') || ']' from dual;

'['||TZ_O
---------
[+01:00 ]
```

with what appears to be an extra space; although copying and pasting that from the SQL Developer worksheet - where it is displayed like that - loses the closing bracket too:

```
'['||TZ_O
---------
[+01:00
```

Dumping the generated value shows the problem:

```
select dump('[' || tz_offset('Europe/Amsterdam') || ']') from dual;

DUMP('['||TZ_OFFSET('EUROPE/AMSTERDAM')||']')
---------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=9: 91,43,48,49,58,48,48,0,93
```

Notice the 0 byte, which is a null character, and causing confusion.

As the offset format is fixed, you can avoid this via a simple `substr()`:

```
select '[' || substr(tz_offset('Europe/Amsterdam'), 1, 6) || ']' from dual;

'['||SUB
--------
[+01:00]

select dump('[' || substr(tz_offset('Europe/Amsterdam'), 1, 6) || ']') from dual;

DUMP('['||SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET('EUROPE/AMSTERDAM'),1,6)||']')
---------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=8: 91,43,48,49,58,48,48,93
```

... or the `replace()` or `trim()` options mentioned in comments; or anything else that removes the rogue character; even:

```
rtrim(tz_offset('Europe/Amsterdam'), chr(0))
```

As the bugs aren't visible in MoS I'm not sure when (or if) it was fixed. It looks like it exists in 11.2.0.0, and I'm see thing in 11.2.0.4 - it may be fixed in 12c. I'm not seeing it in 12.1.0.2.

Comment: `replace(problem_string, chr(0), null)` - length independent way

Comment: Length is always 6 (or 7 including the null byte) in this case, but yes...

Comment: I use `TRIM(TRAILING CHR(0) FROM TZ_OFFSET('Europe/Amsterdam'))`