# Concatenate is not working for content of Oracle unified_audit_trail field SQL_TEXT

Tags: oracle

I am trying to add (concat) some string to the content of the field SQL_TEXT of Oracle view unified_audit_trail. The concatenation is NOT done - string is not added.

The testing script is below.

```
declare 
v_SP_record         clob;
cursor c1 is select * from unified_audit_trail
where sql_text is not null
order by event_timestamp;

begin
  
for rec in c1 loop
v_SP_record := 
'USER: '   || rec.dbusername || ' '  
|| 'TIME: '   || to_char(rec.event_timestamp) || ' ' 
|| 'SQL_TEXT: '  || rec.sql_text  || '<CLOSE>' ;
dbms_output.put_line(v_SP_record);
end loop;
  
end;
```

Checking the output I can see that the string part `<CLOSE>` is not added to the v_SP_record.

An example of the output (some rows out of many in unified_audit_trail) is as below:

```
USER: SYS TIME: 15-NOV-21 01.37.46.289000 AM SQL_TEXT: -- Created on 6/20/2019 by ADMINISTRATOR 
declare 
begin

 dbms_audit_mgmt.clean_audit_trail(
  AUDIT_TRAIL_TYPE => DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.AUDIT_TRAIL_UNIFIED,
  USE_LAST_ARCH_TIMESTAMP => FALSE 
  );
  
end;

USER: OMEGACAEVDBA TIME: 15-NOV-21 01.42.49.679000 AM SQL_TEXT: select mdsys.GetMdsysEvent() from dual
USER: OMEGACAEVDBA TIME: 15-NOV-21 01.42.49.710000 AM SQL_TEXT: select sys.dbms_standard.dictionary_obj_type from dual
USER: OMEGACAEVDBA TIME: 15-NOV-21 01.42.49.741000 AM SQL_TEXT: select mdsys.GetMdsysEvent() from dual
USER: OMEGACAEVDBA TIME: 15-NOV-21 01.42.49.741000 AM SQL_TEXT: select sys.dbms_standard.dictionary_obj_type from dual
USER: OMEGACAEVDBA TIME: 15-NOV-21 01.42.49.757000 AM SQL_TEXT: -- Name = RUN1
grant drop any table to OMEGACAEVDEV1 with admin option
```

The `<CLOSE>` string is NOT added after rec.sql_text.
This behavior has been verified on Oracle 12c R2, 18c and 19c

What kind of characters in the content of SQL_TEXT can cause a concatenation failure?
And how to remove them - or get the right result?

best regards

Altin

Comment: Which client are you running this in? Could it just be treating `<CLOSE>` as an HTML tag and hiding it during display? Otherwise, does `sql_text` end with a null character?

Comment: Thank you @alex

Comment: This is not a matter of any client, because it happens even internally. I am trying to JSON format the audit record so that I send it to some SIEM via UTL_TCP. When the string is not properly formatted (because of the concatenation not done) I do not get the record on the other side. If I comment delivery of SQL_TEXT then it does upload.

I will try to check for a null character in the end. but I do not know how. I did tried using TRIM on sql_text value but nothing changed with that.

Comment: You would need to trim `chr(0)`, not the default space. You can also use `dump()` to inspect the value in the table.

Comment: I tried with the translate as in question 2268860. Added a variable v_sql_text clob, and tried to clear as:

v_sql_text := translate(
           translate(
               translate(rec.sql_text, CHR(10), '')
           , CHR(13), '')
       , CHR(09), '');

Then used its value preparing the v_SP_record.

This time I get the <CLOSE> string in the end, but the variable v_sql_text becomes null, and output looks like

USER: SYS TIME: 15-NOV-21 01.37.46.289000 AM SQL_TEXT: <CLOSE>
USER: OMEGACAEVDBA TIME: 15-NOV-21 01.42.49.679000 AM SQL_TEXT: <CLOSE>

Comment: Tried also with

v_sql_text := trim(replace(replace(rec.sql_text, chr(13)),chr(10)));

this time the SQL string is completed but <CLOSE> is lost again

Comment: You should trim (or replace) `chr(0)`, not 10 or 13 (or 9). It's something of a guess that it's a null character - though I have seen something [slightly similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43004158/266304) before - but it doesn't look like a carriage return, new line or tab issue, as that would be unlikely to cause the string to be truncated.

Comment: thank you @AlexPoole

I did replace(v_sql_text,chr(0),''); and the concatenation was done OK.
Are you aware of any other special character that can have the same effect like chr(0)?

best regards
Altin
ps, your comment is the answer. I will acknowledge as such if you post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenation is happening. It appears that `sql_text` is terminated by a null character, which has been noted with other values and results. After concatenation that null character is in the middle of your generated string.

Essentially you're ending up with:

```
USER: ... SQL_TEXT: select mdsys.GetMdsysEvent() from dual<NUL><CLOSE>
                                                          ^^^^^
                                        null character, ASCII 0
```

How that is handled depends on the client (some clients will not show the full concatenated string; others will show it but you won't be able to copy it; others might just show it without it doing anything odd) and what you do with it.

As a null character is used to mark the end of a variable-length string in many places (e.g. C strings; but not internally in Oracle varchars) it's not surprising that it causes your generated string - after your concatenation - to be truncated somewhere down the line. Everything after it is discarded or at least ignored and not used in further processing - in your client, or `utl_tcp`, or both.

You can replace the null character, either after concatenation with:

```
v_SP_record := <your current concatenation>;
v_SP_record := replace(v_SP_record, chr(0), null)
```

or before concatenation with:

```
v_SP_record := ... || replace(rec.sql_text, chr(0), null) || '<CLOSE>';
```

Or you can trim it from the raw `sql_text` value, before concatenation, with:

```
v_SP_record := ... || rtrim(rec.sql_text, chr(0)) || '<CLOSE>';
```

or:

```
v_SP_record := ... || trim(trailing chr(0) from rec.sql_text) || '<CLOSE>';
```

I'd probably use one of the trim options, and the last one is perhaps most self-explanatory for someone trying to understand the code later (though a comment explaining why it's there is still a good idea of course, whichever method you use).